# Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map method Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a problem with appropriate mapping to endpoints. I want to get result like this:

- When I go to `/api/leagues/1` show league with id=1,
- When I go to `/api/leagues/spain` show league with country="spain",
- When I go to `/api/leagues/la liga` show league with leagueName="la liga"

my code is like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/leagues")
public class LeagueController {

    @Autowired
    private LeagueService leagueService;

    @GetMapping("")
    public List<League> getLeagues() {
        return leagueService.getAllLeagues();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public League getLeagueById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return leagueService.getLeagueById(id);
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public League getLeagueByCountry(@RequestParam(value="country") String country) {
        return leagueService.getLeagueByCountry(country);
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public League getLeagueByLeagueName(@RequestParam(value="leagueName") String leagueName) {
        return leagueService.getLeagueByLeagueName(leagueName);
    }


}
```

However, when running I get the following error message:

```
Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'leagueController' method`
```

When I change my code like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/leagues")
public class LeagueController {

    @Autowired
    private LeagueService leagueService;

    @GetMapping("")
    public List<League> getLeagues() {
        return leagueService.getAllLeagues();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public League getLeagueById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return leagueService.getLeagueById(id);
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public League getLeagueByCountry(@RequestParam(value="country") String country) {
        return leagueService.getLeagueByCountry(country);
    }

}
```

It works, but then I should use the following endpoint:

```
/api/leagues?country=spain
```

But I prefer having this endpoint in stead:

```
/api/leagues/spain
```

Can someone explain me how I can solve problem or help me find a solution for the mapping I want? I will be grateful for that.

Answer (score 0):

The error is rather clear according to your experimentation.
You cannot have more than one `@GetMapping("...")` with the same path whatever the signature of the method.
While this code compiles, it is not enough at runtime for Spring :

```
@GetMapping("/")
public League getLeagueByCountry(@RequestParam(value="country") String country) {
    return leagueService.getLeagueByCountry(country);
}

@GetMapping("/")
public League getLeagueByLeagueName(@RequestParam(value="leagueName") String leagueName) {
    return leagueService.getLeagueByLeagueName(leagueName);
}
```

---

> not like i want to:
>
> `/api/leagues/spain`

To get such a mapping where I suppose spain is a country among others : the country information should be specified as a `@PathVariable` parameter :

```
@GetMapping("/{country}")
public League getLeagueByCountry(@PathVariable String country) {
    return leagueService.getLeagueByCountry(country);
}
```